# How to I get new values from dynamic table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I want to create dynamic table that loads localStorage saved form data and make it editable.

I can change cells values but when I try to save it JavaScript `console.log();` prints me old values.

When I inspect html values in cells that I have changed it looks okay, but still javascript gets old values that have been loaded from localStorage.

I just don't get it, am I supposed to refresh somehow javascript?

```js
$(".table-add").click(function() {
    let TABLE = $("table");
    document.getElementById("load-local").className += " hide";
    let load = TABLE
        .find("tr.hide")
        .clone(true)
        .removeClass("hide table-line");
    TABLE.append(load);
});
$(".table-remove").click(function() {
    $(this)
        .parents("tr")
        .detach();
    document.getElementById("load-local").className = "table-add glyphicon glyphicon-refresh";
});

$(".table-save").click(function() {
  const userEdit = {};
  userEdit['fname'] = document.getElementById('fname').innerHTML;
  userEdit['lname'] = document.getElementById('lname').innerHTML;
  userEdit['email'] = document.getElementById('email').innerHTML;
  userEdit['phone'] = document.getElementById('phone').innerHTML;
  userEdit['gender'] = document.getElementById('gender').innerHTML;
  console.log(userEdit);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css" />
<script src="js/table.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>HTML5 Editable Table</h1>
  <div id="table" class="table-editable">
    <span id="load-local" class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Imię</th>
        <th>Nazwisko</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Telefon</th>
        <th>Płeć</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <!-- This is our cloneable table line -->
      <tr class="hide">
        <td contenteditable="true" id="fname">Name</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="lname">Surname</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="email">foobar@example.com</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="phone">123123123</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="gender">other</td>
        <td>
          <span id="remove-local" class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="save-local" class="table-save glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to make you a snippet. I had to comment out the hide. The code seems to work. Not sure what your exact issue is. localStorage does not work here at SO so I commented it out, but you seem to be storing the data correctly

Comment: Huh. That's so weird because in my Firefox browser when I ```console.log();``` my edited values I get old ones loaded from localStorage instead of new ones but here it works...

Comment: Just double checked on Google Chrome and it's the same issue as in Firefox browser, no matter which values I edit in table still the output which I get are old values

Comment: Works for me https://plungjan.name/SO/localsave/

Comment: @mplungjan My bad, I just figured out that if this table is loaded static (already has cells because of ```---hide```) is works like it supposed to, but if it's loaded dynamicly via ```.table-add``` it doesn't work and that's my problem

Comment: IDs must be unique within an HTML document. You can not just clone an element that has descendants with static IDs, and then expect this to work properly.

Comment: @CBroe okay, thanks for explanation. I didn't know that. So is there a workaround?

Comment: There is no "workaround", but you can use classes. Classes are for elements which appear multiple times in the DOM. You need to update your JS then tough.

Answer (score 0):

IDs need to be unique

Use class and relative addressing

I simplified some more code. DOM access is ugly when mixed into jQuery

```js
const $table = $("table");
$(".table-add").click(function() {
  $("#load-local").hide()
  let load =  $table
    .find("tr.hide")
    .clone(true)
    .removeClass("hide table-line");
   $table.append(load);
});
$(".table-remove").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove()
  $("#load-local").show()
});

$(".table-save").click(function() {
  const userEdit = {}
  $(this).closest("tr").find("td[contenteditable]").each(function() {
    userEdit[this.className] = this.textContent
  })
  console.log(userEdit);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css" />
<script src="js/table.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>HTML5 Editable Table</h1>
  <div id="table" class="table-editable">
    <span id="load-local" class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Imię</th>
        <th>Nazwisko</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Telefon</th>
        <th>Płeć</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <!-- This is our cloneable table line -->
      <tr class="hide">
        <td contenteditable="true" class="fname">Name</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="lname">Surname</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="email">foobar@example.com</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="phone">123123123</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="gender">other</td>
        <td>
          <span id="remove-local" class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="save-local" class="table-save glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```